# RegEx Extraction #NAME error

Tags: regex, vba, excel

I'm trying to create my own VBA Function based on the one in step two at this link. [How to use Regular Expressions (Regex) in Microsoft Excel both in-cell and loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22542834/how-to-use-regular-expressions-regex-in-microsoft-excel-both-in-cell-and-loops)

However, I get a #NAME error. Where am I going wrong here? I've tested my RegEx on https://regex101.com.

```
Function extractGroupName(Myrange As Range) As String
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    Dim strPattern As String
    Dim strInput As String
    Dim strReplace As String
    Dim strOutput As String

    strPattern = "^.*Name:(.*);Id"

    If strPattern <> "" Then
        strInput = Myrange.Value
        strReplace = "$1"

        With regEx
            .Global = True
            .MultiLine = True
            .IgnoreCase = False
            .Pattern = strPattern
        End With

        If regEx.Test(strInput) Then
            extractGroupName = regEx.Replace(strInput, "$1")
        Else
            extractGroupName = "ERROR: NOT FOUND"
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Are you calling this function from a worksheet cell, and the return in the cell is #NAME?  If that is the case, where did you put the code?  It should normally be in a Regular module in the same workbook.  Did you name the module with the same name as the function?  Also, did you set a reference to Regular Expressions under tools/references?

Comment: Yes, I am calling this from a worksheet cell, and the return in the cell is #NAME.

The code is in a module in the workbook.

The module and function do have the same name.

I have turned on the reference to regular expressions.

Everything works fine when I copy-paste the code in step 2 of the link I provided verbatim, however when I do this, it causes the #NAME error, implying it's an issue with code, not naming schema, location, or references.

Comment: How and where did you put the VBA code?

Comment: Sorry, just edited my original reply. Accidentally hit enter early.

Comment: If your module and function have the same name, Excel does not know which you are referring to.  So they need to have different names, or you need to use a fully qualified name.

Comment: Whelp. That did it. Thank you!

Comment: I will add that as an answer in the thread, with a more full explanation and suggestions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you have named the module and the function the same.  When that happens, Excel doesn't know which you mean, so returns the #NAME error.  There are two fixes:

1. Change the name of one or the other.  I will frequently prefix all regular module names with `mod` so as to avoid this problem:  `modextractGroupName`
2. Call the function with a fully qualified name:

---

```
=extractGroupName.extractGroupName(A1)
```

---

Answer (score 0):

Looks to me that you are missing the reference to the Reg Expression library. 
I think this is Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions in the References dialog box (Tools:Referneces in the VBIDE)...

Comment: Except when I use the one from the example verbatim, it works. I've already turned on the reference.

Comment: If there were a missing reference, it would give a compile error in the vbe, not a #NAME error in the cell.

Comment: Ah, so if you execute in the Immediate window (a.k.a. the Debug Window) it works, right? Make sure the function is in a Module and not in the worksheet class. This will also cause that.